# Compare strings if something is the same 2 times

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Something like:

```py
string_one = "hello world one"
string_two = "hello john one"
if string_one = string_two:
    do something
```

So if it detects 2 words in 2 (or more) strings that are the same do something. But I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You can separate the sentences into a set of words and test if there is an intersection of at least 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split()` to turn the strings into lists of words, then turn them into `set`s so you can take the intersection and see if its `len` is greater than 2.

```
>>> string_one = "hello world one"
>>> string_two = "hello john one"
>>> set(string_one.split()) & set(string_two.split())
{'hello', 'one'}
>>> if len(set(string_one.split()) & set(string_two.split())) >= 2:
...     print("at least two words are the same!")
...
at least two words are the same!
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comparison

```
string_one = "hello world one"
string_two = "hello john one"

matched = [i for i in string_one.split() if i in string_two.split()]
print(matched)
```

## output List

```
['hello', 'one']
>>>
```

You can set condition by

```
print(len(matched))
```

output length

```
2
```

Uisng condition accordingly

```
if(len(matched)) >=2:
    print("2 or more sub words matched")
```